# HTML/CSS - Responsive 3 column navigation bar

Tags: html, css, alignment, multiple-columns

Really struggling with how to implement this.

I want to make a navigation bar, 960px centred on the page. Within this navigation bar are 3 different sections, or columns. The far left one is at minimum, 200px. The middle one is ALWAYS centered, and always 20px. The far right one is at minimum 300px, and aligned to the right. At the full 960px, it'd look like this:
[image]

At 740px, it'd look like this:
[image]

At 620px, it'd look like this:
[image]

At 520px, it'd look like this:
[image]

And below that it'd go into some alternate design, so don't worry about that.
What's the best way to go about doing this?

edit: This is what I've got at the moment. It works at 960px, but the middle div doesn't stay in the centre when you resize it, because of the padding. It also falls apart when it goes too small, goes onto 2 lines.

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}
.middle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 100px;
    height: 39px;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you need a maximum width as well, otherwise there may never be that blank space between the columns on the left and right and the middle one.

Comment: What do you mean by centered? In you're 960px and 740px the middle div is centered, but in the 520px view it's off-centered to the left.

Comment: Looks to me like you want the left and right columns to grow in width as the browser reduces in width, right? If so, I don't think this can be accomplished with just CSS. You likely need JavaScript.

Comment: @JoeyP I added 620px, which is where it might change - up until that point, the middle div is centered. Past that point, the div would just be aligned to the right div. So I guess I only need the design to work from 960px to 620px. Past that it's pretty easy

Comment: @JudeOsborn No, they look like they're growing cos the image gets resized. Open the images in a new tab if you're confused.

Comment: Is there a maximum width on either the pink or green columns?  Is the yellow column going to have content in it (or can it be a background image)?

Comment: There's no max width, only a minimum width needed. They have to fit in  a certain amount of buttons. The yellow column is just a single image button.

Comment: Is it intended that the middle div is centered relative to the page until one of the side divs begins to push on it?

Comment: What should happen below 520px?

Comment: @thgaskell yes, that's correct.

Comment: @cimmanon Below 520px it would be a different design for tablets/mobiles. But 520px is just an arbitrary number here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one because it does require pixel perfect media queries to pull off:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/cmJhx

```
<nav>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div><!--
  --><div class="c">c</div>
</nav>
```

Note the commented out whitespace ^^

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 620px) {
  nav {
    text-align: right;
  }

  nav div {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .a {
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 620px) {
  nav {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .a {
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
  }

  .b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }

  .c {
    float: right;
    min-width: 300px;
  }
}

/* colors! */

.a {
  background: green;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.b {
  background: yellow;
  width: 20px;
}

.c {
  background: pink;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

The problem, of course, is if your first/last elements aren't large enough to contain their children.  Because the middle element is absolutely positioned to be in the middle of the page at the 620px breakpoint, there can't be any room for error.

Comment: Very nice work! Also very nice and simple having just 3 divs, and in the right order too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should only need one media query here.  In the example below as the window shrinks the yellow div will be centered until 620px when it will slide along with the pink div until 520px when it will scroll.  Not sure if you were looking for this or @jhunlio's solution.

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-col"></div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="middle-col"></div>
        <div class="right-col"></div>
        <br class="clean" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
}
.clean{
  clear: both;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 520px;
}
.inner-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: calc(50% + 10px);
  height: 100%;
}
.left-col{
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
.middle-col{
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.right-col{
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 620px){
  .inner-wrapper{
    width: auto; 
  }
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BkFup/2/

Comment: This would be exactly what I want.. but this just has the yellow div stuck to the pink div the whole way?

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div class="navWrap">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="navLeft"></div>
        <div class="navCenterWrap">
            <div class="navCenter"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="navRight"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.navWrap {margin:auto; width:960px;}
.nav {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.navLeft {
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    padding:10px 0;
    background-color:green;
}
.navCenterWrap {
    margin:auto;
    width:5%;
}
.navCenter {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px 0;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.navRight {
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    padding:10px 0;
    background-color:blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px){ 
    .navWrap {
        width:100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 520px){ 
    .navWrap {
        width:100%;
    }
    .navLeft {
      width:40%; 
        margin:0;
    }
    .navCenterWrap {
        width:5%;
        float:left;
    }
    .navRight {
        width:55%;
        margin:0;
    }
}
```

note: *scroll the fiddle to see the effect* 
working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/RgywE/7/)

Comment: This is what I want, but I need it to be fluid, not just changing at certain thresholds.

Comment: you say that you want `960px wrapper` but if you want it more fluid layout just eliminate `960px` to `100%`